Conditional JSONPAth in nested Json
I have a nested json where products.productOffering is repeated under different nested structure.I need to write a single conditional JSON path for getting id field in product array based on product.productOffering.type and product.productOffering.subtype.
As products Array is repeated under different node. What is best way to get condition json irrespective of position of Products Array
{"status": 200,
"code": 200,
"message": "",
"time": "",
"correlationId": "",
"requestId": "",
"method": "GET",
"data": {
    "productCollections": [
        {
            "customerId": "",
            "accountId": "",
            "products": [
                {
                    *"id": "123",*
                    "status": "Active",
                    "startDate": "2023-05-18",
                    "productOffering": {
                        "id": "abc",
                        "name": "",
                        "type": "PLAN",
                        "subtype": "STANDALONE"
                    },
                    "productRelationships": [
                        {
                            "type": "SERVICE",
                            "products": [
                                {
                                    "id": "123",
                                    "status": "Active",
                                    "startDate": "2023-05-18",
                                    "productOffering": {
                                        "id": "",
                                        "name": "",
                                        "type": "SERVICE",
                                        "subtype": "MOBILE"
                                    },
                                    "productRelationships": [
                                        {
                                            "type": "ADDON",
                                            "products": [
                                                {
                                                    "id": "123",
                                                    "status": "Active",
                                                    "startDate": "2023-05-18",
                                                    "productOffering": {
                                                        "id": "",
                                                        "name": "",
                                                        "type": "Test",
                                                        "subtype": "SPEED"
                                                    },
                                                    "productAttributes": {},
                                                    "productRelationships": []
                                                },
                                                {
                                                    "id": "",
                                                    "status": "Active",
                                                    "startDate": "2023-05-18",
                                                    "productOffering": {
                                                        "id": "123",
                                                        "name": "Pass",
                                                        "type": "ADDON",
                                                        "subtype": "DAYPASS"
                                                    },
                                                    "productAttributes": {},
                                                    "productRelationships": []
                                                }
                                            ]
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}

}
